# Tomorrow, today and yesterday with MomentJS

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'd like the `moment().fromNow()` functionality, but when the date is close it is too precise - ex. I don't want it to show 'in 3 hours' but 'today' - so basically with a 'daily' precision.

I tried using the `moment().calendar()` function, it doesn't format if the date difference is more than 1 day

Answer (score 195):

You can also do this to get the date for today and tomorrow and yesterday

```
let today     = moment();

let tomorrow  = moment().add(1,'days');

let yesterday = moment().add(-1, 'days');
```

Comment: this is not in the official api! please provide the polyfill you have for this

Comment: see the docs here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/ The only thing I add is the `new Date()` to avoid a warning the lib keeps giving me (see https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/)

Comment: It's true, I really added it as a reference for myself and others who might end up here because of how the title of the question is phrased. Looks like it helped a lot of people, which I'm happy about. :)

Comment: https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/mutability/
Isnt this the official usage of 'add'?

Comment: @AndrewDay for existing variables that is the right way, except in this case `moment()` creates a new Moment object, so it's not necessary.

Comment: I'm also really surprised this is the top voted answer. It answers a completely different question. It's like asking "How you you spell 'time'?" and the top-voted answer being "Well, I know that 'date' is spelled D-A-T-E, so there's that."

Comment: Actually you can run into problems if you are using time, not only date. If you execute this method today at 2pm it will return moment object of tomorrow 2pm, so it can be tricky when it comes to time! It only adds 24 hours to current object

Answer (score 54):

I use a combination of `add()` and `endOf()` with moment

```
//...
const today = moment().endOf('day')
const tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'day').endOf('day')

if (date < today) return 'today'
if (date < tomorrow) return 'tomorrow'
return 'later'
//...
```

[EDIT 2022-01-04] I suggest you to use now dayjs which has the very same API as moment and is lightweight ;)

Comment: this isn't translated

Comment: @evanjmg the translation was not part of the original question. But feel free to use any i18n translating method to translate the 3 keys used in the snippet

Comment: you're missing the point. Moment locale should handle everything for you without logic like this. Use moment.calendar instead. If logic isn't necessary here

Answer (score 45):

You can customize the way that both the `.fromNow` and the `.calendar` methods display dates using `moment.updateLocale`.  The following code will change the way that `.calendar` displays as per the question:

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    calendar : {
        lastDay : '[Yesterday]',
        sameDay : '[Today]',
        nextDay : '[Tomorrow]',
        lastWeek : '[Last] dddd',
        nextWeek : '[Next] dddd',
        sameElse : 'L'
    }
});
```

Based on the question, it seems like the `.calendar` method would be more appropriate -- `.fromNow` wants to have a past/present prefix/suffix, but if you'd like to find out more you can read the documentation at http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/.

To use this in only one place instead of overwriting the locales, pass a string of your choice as the first argument when you define the `moment.updateLocale` and then invoke the calendar method using that locale (eg. `moment.updateLocale('yesterday-today').calendar( /* moment() or whatever */ )`)

**EDIT:** Moment ^2.12.0 now has the `updateLocale` method. `updateLocale` and `locale` appear to be functionally the same, and `locale` isn't yet deprecated, but updated the answer to use the newer method.

Comment: this changes the global localization, I just need this in 1 place :)

Comment: See edit -- you can create custom locales instead of overwriting existing locales

Answer (score 44):

**Requirements:**

- When the date is further away, use the standard `moment().fromNow()` functionality.
- When the date is closer, show `"today"`, `"yesterday"`, `"tomorrow"`, etc.

**Solution:**

```
// call this function, passing-in your date
function dateToFromNowDaily( myDate ) {

    // get from-now for this date
    var fromNow = moment( myDate ).fromNow();

    // ensure the date is displayed with today and yesterday
    return moment( myDate ).calendar( null, {
        // when the date is closer, specify custom values
        lastWeek: '[Last] dddd',
        lastDay:  '[Yesterday]',
        sameDay:  '[Today]',
        nextDay:  '[Tomorrow]',
        nextWeek: 'dddd',
        // when the date is further away, use from-now functionality             
        sameElse: function () {
            return "[" + fromNow + "]";
        }
    });
}
```

NB: From version 2.14.0, the formats argument to the calendar function can be a callback, see http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/.

Answer (score 23):

You can use this:

```
const today     = moment();

const tomorrow  = moment().add(1, 'days');

const yesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'days');
```

Comment: duplicate answer of HussienK

Comment: but he posted 1st?

Comment: yap, but this is changed post

Answer (score 17):

Here is how I do that using [moment](https://momentjs.com/):

```
  let today = moment().format('DD MMMM YYYY');

  let tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'days').format('DD MMMM YYYY').toString();

  let yesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'days').startOf('day').format('DD MMMM YYYY').toString();
```

Answer (score 16):

I have similar solution, but allows to use locales:

```
    let date = moment(someDate);
    if (moment().diff(date, 'days') >= 2) {
        return date.fromNow(); // '2 days ago' etc.
    }
    return date.calendar().split(' ')[0]; // 'Yesterday', 'Today', 'Tomorrow'
```

Comment: it works, but if you change '>=1' for '>=2' then you will get 'yesterday' string instead of '1 day ago'.

Answer (score 15):

From 2.10.5 moment supports specifying calendar output formats per invocation
For a more detailed documentation check [Moment - Calendar](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/).

```
**Moment 2.10.5**
moment().calendar(null, {
  sameDay: '[Today]',
  nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
  nextWeek: 'dddd',
  lastDay: '[Yesterday]',
  lastWeek: '[Last] dddd',
  sameElse: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});
```

From 2.14.0 calendar can also take a callback to return values.

```
**Moment 2.14.0**
    moment().calendar(null, {
     sameDay: function (now) {
       if (this.isBefore(now)) {
         return '[Will Happen Today]';
       } else {
        return '[Happened Today]';
       }
       /* ... */
      }
    });
```

Comment: why the downvotes ? Let me know so that I can improve this ans

Comment: This is answer.

Comment: this is the correct answer I think. But it still does not returns "3 days ago" type result unless highly customized

Answer (score 10):

In Moment.js, the [from()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/) method has the daily precision you're looking for:

```
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
yesterday.setDate(today.getDate()-1);

moment(today).from(moment(yesterday)); // "in a day"
moment(today).from(moment(tomorrow)); // "a day ago" 

moment(yesterday).from(moment(tomorrow)); // "2 days ago" 
moment(tomorrow).from(moment(yesterday)); // "in 2 days"
```

Comment: thanks, but it still doesn't display 'today', and displays ex. '1 day ago' instead of 'yesterday' - looks like the functionality I need needs to be custom

Comment: `from` doesn't really have daily precision. For example, if yesterday was four hours ago and I pick a time that was five hours ago, it will say "5 hours ago" instead of yesterday. This solution has nothing to do with the precision of `from`, but of the dates passed in.

Answer (score 9):

So this is what I ended up doing

```
var dateText = moment(someDate).from(new Date());
var startOfToday = moment().startOf('day');
var startOfDate = moment(someDate).startOf('day');
var daysDiff = startOfDate.diff(startOfToday, 'days');
var days = {
  '0': 'today',
  '-1': 'yesterday',
  '1': 'tomorrow'
};

if (Math.abs(daysDiff) <= 1) {
  dateText = days[daysDiff];
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but I need to apply i18n, and I have 10 languages...so I was relying on the momentJS internationalization...

Answer (score 4):

You can use .add() and .subtract() method to get yesterday and tomorrow date. Then use format method to get only date .format("D/M/Y"), D stand for Day, M for Month, Y for Year. [Check in Moment Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

```
 let currentMilli = Date.now()
 let today = Moment(currentMilli).format("D/M/Y");
 let tomorrow = Moment(currentMilli).add(1, 'days').format("D/M/Y");
 let yesterday = Moment(currentMilli).subtract(1, 'days').format("D/M/Y");
```

Result will be:

```
Current Milli - 1576693800000
today - 19/12/2019
tomorrow - 18/12/2019
yesterday - 18/12/2019
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const date = moment(YOUR_DATE)
return (moment().diff(date, 'days') >= 2) ? date.fromNow() : date.calendar().split(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Add Past and future date in Date time picker in react-native**

```
import DateTimePickerModal from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";
import moment from 'moment';


 let addFutureDay = new Date();
    addFutureDay = moment(addFutureDay).add(2, 'day').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    const FutureMonthAdd = moment(addFutureDay, 'MM/DD/YYYY').toDate();
   
    let addPastDate = new Date();
    addPastDate = moment(addPastDate).add(-2, 'day').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    const PastMonthAdd = moment(addPastDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY').toDate();

    return (
        <View>
            <Text> DatePickerDemo </Text>
            <Button title="Show Date Picker" onPress={showDatePicker} />
            <DateTimePickerModal
                isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
                mode="date"
                minimumDate={PastMonthAdd}
                maximumDate={FutureMonthAdd}
                onConfirm={handleConfirm}
                onCancel={hideDatePicker}
            />

        </View>
    )
```

const formatedDate=  moment(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss a")

const formatedDate2=  moment(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm A")      // DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm a

Comment: must be install react-native community library also