# Assigning +1 at current date in JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following code and it works fine:

```
function currentdate() {
    var _today = moment().format("YYYYMMDD");
}
```

But I would like to write a new one that will look like this and it would store tomorrow's date:

```
function tomorrowdate() {
    var _tomorrow = moment().format("YYYYMMDD");
}
```

So I assume that I have to do something like

```
moment()+1.format("YYYYMMDD");
```

Tested this, but it didnt work.
Which is the proper way to give next day's date at my _tomorrow variable?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/38599576/5104748

Comment: [Why not just check the Moment documentation?](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js - tomorrow, today and yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35441820/moment-js-tomorrow-today-and-yesterday)

Comment: Thanks guys. I've checked the documentation but im unable to format it using my YYYYMMDD appearance

Comment: @JohnGreco The answer work. Check http://jsfiddle.net/460oex3p/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get next day where 1 is for number you want to add and days is for that number would be added in days. There are other options also weeks, years etc. We have chained the add function with format so that your dates are in same format as in today function.

```
moment().add(1, 'days').format('YYYYMMDD');
```

For more details refer to 
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

I also suggest you move date format to some constant if it is same across your code and use that const instead of writing string everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

If you're already using momentjs, it has functions for manipulating days :

```
    moment().add(1, 'days').format('YYYYMMDD');
```

Comment: Lots of thanks for your answer! 
Im trying to format it using the same format I do use for my current variable of _today. I understand that moment(new Date()).add(1,'days'); will return the next day, however im searching for a way to format it in YYYYMMDD. Any ideas? I tried your code but it failed. Probably a typo?

Comment: No, `.format('yyyyMMdd')` return incorrect result.http://jsfiddle.net/460oex3p/1/

Comment: Ugh, thanks again @Mohammad.  I was reading the docs, and they have the year and day as lowercase.  Just corrected (again).